# how to edit resourceHints links from bigcommerce?

Tags: html, seo, bigcommerce, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

I need bit of help here as I don't know where to edit {{resourceHints}} files which automatically added to top section of bigcommerce website.

I also found this resource from BigCommerce but don't know what to do further from here: [bigcommerce resourceHints](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/handlebars-helpers-reference#resourcehints)

Why I want to edit them? - Because google crawler doing crawling to the site and its detecting 404 page from below link:

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/" crossorigin>
```

Now to avoid google to crawling the above link I need to add "nofollow" attribute to rel of the above line. So that google doesn't try to go to this external link and mark them as 404 page not found list.

[image]

OR
if anyone know how to add this in robots.txt file so that the above links are not getting crawl by google.
OR
how to fix this by any other way.

Thanks in advance and if you've any question regarding this to me then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remove that line and add my own hints directly to the code.

For robots.txt editing, go into admin->settings and search for "robots". Select the "Website" option, and scroll down to the editor.

It's quite strange that Google is picking up that link and crawling it. Where is it reporting them as 404 pages?

Comment: yes we received that from SEO team and yes its reporting them as 404 page

Comment: One more question: can we add nofollow attribute to link tag? <link rel="nofollow dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" crossorigin>

Comment: What was telling the SEO team about the 404s? I don't know of any way you can monitor Googlebot initiated 404s for someone else's domain. I've never heard of adding a nofollow to a link tag, so I don't know if it will have any effect. Google sometimes discovers links in strange ways and just tries them out.

Comment: SEO team gave us the list of all the 404s links which include the above link too. I also try to explain them that we can't control other domains 404s. So what's the solution here? As you said that nofollow has no effect when google do the crawling so is thr any other way to address this issue?

Comment: But what told the SEO team? Most likely this is a non issue coming from the SEO team using a tool that invents possible problems.

Comment: That sort of 404 is not an issue. The href in a preconnect is not used beyond connecting to the domain. The supplied href is not visited.